# Tweak "Send To..." option in nautilus

Tags: nautilus

I much like Windows 7's windows explorer's "Send to" menu. It's very useful and I can tweak this for my own need. I see nautilus has the same feature, but I don't know how to tweak this (for example, add or remove extra options). Is there any way to do this?

I have tweaked "Send to" options in windows explorer. See the screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of Windows 7' Send to menu]

Comment: Could you explain more? I can choose "send to" "removable drive". See: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4098082/Send%20To.png

Comment: Screenshot added. See options, evernote and custom added location. I want to add custom location or application shortcut like windows explorer

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can tweak Nautilus.
You can put scripts at the folder `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/` and you will see then when you right click on a file or a folder. At [G-scripts](http://g-scripts.sourceforge.net/faq.php) you will find some instructions and examples.

[R Srijith](http://blog.sriunplugged.com/about/) has made a [send to script](http://blog.sriunplugged.com/shell-scripting/send-to-in-linux/) that you can begin with.

Comment: Apart from script is there any option? Nautilus scripts are buggy and memory hogging. I have tried and ends in nautilus nearly taking all of my memory. Without script, nautilus is fine

Comment: I will search and put here if I found something.

Comment: Script is now a dead link.

Answer (score 4):

Your response is -> Nautilus Actions (since 19.10+ [`filemanager-actions`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031746/349837)). So type in terminal the following line:

```
sudo apt-get install nautilus-actions
```

then search for *nautilus-actions tutorial*. There are just 2 or 3 easy steps to learn how to use this strong tool.

Practically you can do exactly what you want. You can add some contextual menu entries for Nautilus right-click and you can map different actions. Some actions are ready made on Internet most of them are [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20120424142130/http://www.grumz.net/?q=configlist).

Comment: Can you please write those "2 or three" easy steps here?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the original question directly :

No the average person can not easily edit or customise the Send To context menu in nautilus.

The reason is that those entries are actually Plugins to the `nautilus-sendto` program, which are stored on your computers filesystem as `.so` files (similar to windows .dll).

So there you have it, it's not easy for the non programmer to create `.so` files.

In my humble opinion the send-to context menu **should** build its menu based on `.desktop` files in `~/.local/share/send-to/shortcuts/*` and bash/python/etc scripts in `~/.local/share/send-to/plugins/*`

But gnome developers aren't known for their ability to relate to the common person.