# How does one add items to the "Send to" menu in Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus

You can add items to the `Create document` right-click context menu by simply adding items to `~/Templates`.

Is there a similar method which allows you to add options to the `Send to` context menu of Nautilus, executing the proper script with the file name as a parameter?

Comment: this is a dublicate to http://askubuntu.com/questions/35575/tweak-send-to-option-in-nautilus