# cant transfer files from home to usb?

Tags: 14.04

I dont have the send to option when right click a file and the files are greyed out so am unable to select when trying to copy? please help it was fine before the 14.04 update.

Comment: see here.http://askubuntu.com/questions/35575/tweak-send-to-option-in-nautilus

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, you are not the root user. Follow the instructions below:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Type in the following command and press enter:

   `sudo nautilus`
3. Select a file that you want to transfer and send (right click on file, *Copy To...*) it to any particular location   (including, USB).

**OR**

Follow this:

1. Press, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Use this:

   `cp source-address-of-file-including-file destination-address`

   In your case:
    `cp /home/username/your-file-name.txt /media/username/your-media-name/`

Comment: did as you instructed and got the below......

Comment: failed to register client GDbus error

Comment: @Alan did the file manager open with your home directory ?

Comment: yes but still did not have the send to option

Comment: @Alan there would be a **Copy To** option, when you right click a file. Use it. There is no such **Send To** option.

Comment: Have tried that and the files are greyed out and cant select.  Before the update I could right click the file and had a sent to option which is now not there.

Comment: @Alan substitute **username**, **your-media-name**, **file-name.txt** as per your credentials.

Comment: @Alan http://buff.ly/1vD6h4S This link helps you further.

Comment: @Alan If this answer helped you resolving your problem, **Accept** it as that will help many others facing the same.

Comment: @devGeek **Bolded Text** makes answers harder to read. I have gone ahead and removed it from this post. Please refrain from doing this in the future, unless it is to highlight easily-missed text (like in the middle of a large paragraph) or to highlight extremely important topics. Use *italics* for variables or user-dependent values. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give it a try and copy/paste or move the files within Terminal.

If not you're not handy with Terminal , its about time mate!

I practically do Everything in terminal after several pumps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another file manager, like PCManFM:

```
sudo apt-get install pcmanfm
```

Start it from the dash. You should be able to copy the files you want.